# If a $\{a_n\}$ doesn't converge to $L$ then exists a subsequence such that no subsequence of it converges to $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Claim:** If $a_n$ does not converge to $L$, where $L\in\mathbb{R}$, then there exists a subsequence of $a_n$ with the property that no subsequence of it (sub-subsequence of $a_n$) converges to $L$.

**My attempt:**

I started by negating $a_n \rightarrow L$, which is: $\exists$ $\epsilon_*>0$ such that $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists$ $j\ge N$ so that $|a_j - L| \ge \epsilon_*$

But from here I really don't know where to go..

Any hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From

$\exists$ $\epsilon_*>0$ such that $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists$ $j\ge N$ so that $|a_j - L| \ge \epsilon_*$

we obtain a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$ with

$|a_{n_k} - L| \ge \epsilon_*$  for all $k$.

Each subsequence $(a_{n_{k_j}})$ of $(a_{n_k})$ has the property

$|a_{n_{k_j}} - L| \ge \epsilon_*$  for all $j$.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a sequence $b_n(\epsilon) = \begin{matrix}a_n&if&|a_n - L|>\epsilon \\ K &if &|a_n - L|<\epsilon \end{matrix}$ with $K \ne L$

$b_n$ does not converge to L ( since $a_n$ does not ) and any subsequence of $b_n$ would either converge to $K$ or $\lim_\infty a_n$ or diverge.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $a_n$ does not converges to $L$, then we can find an $\epsilon >0 $ such that $|a_k  - L| \geq \epsilon $ for infinitely many $k$. The subsequence formed by these elements $a_k$ has the required property.